# ionic 2 http request after oauth not working

Tags: ionic-framework, angular, httprequest, ionic2

I have a button redirect to this function

```
loginGoogle() {
    this.cordovaOauthG.login().then((success) => {
      console.log("Google Login DONE ");
      if (success != null) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(success));
        //alert(success.access_token);

        if (success.access_token != null && success.access_token != '') {
          var params = "google_id=" + success.access_token;
          // var token = success.access_token;
          // this.postLoginGoogle(params);
          this.tesLogin();
        }
      }
    }, (error) => {
      alert(error);
    });
  }
```

and this is the function for http request

```
tesLogin(){
    // var params = "google_id="+gid;
    var params = "google_id="+'ya29.Ci_4ApeVHCD7av30Y82JRZPLG4T9ZUgmU1SNLUGIlVV_ufAcCoBc4ILqsY6Ah55i-g';
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    console.log(params);
    this.http.post(Config.base_url + 'api/user-account/login-google', params, {headers: headers})
        .map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
      if (data.success) {
        this.local.set('access_token', data.message);
        this.menu.enable(true);
        this.nav.setRoot(HomePage);
      }
      else {
        this.doAlert("Incorrect email or password");
      }
    });
}
```

My problem is, whenever I tried to call using success.access_token, it doesnt work
but If I am calling the request without any parameters(just throwing in some random strings) then it works
I tried to debug it using mobile inspector from chrome, either way it is returning a error like this (working post & not working post both returning error)
EXCEPTION: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 1

Comment: I already tested the social login result with console.log, it works fine, the only problem here is http request is not working while using data returned from social login (it is fine tho while printed, not null)

Comment: try using `let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });` instead of `headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');` although your doing it as mentioned on : https://auth0.com/blog/2015/10/15/angular-2-series-part-3-using-http/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to send the authentication token in the header not in the parameters. Something like that:

> var headers = new Headers();
>
> headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
>     headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + authToken);